# Swift: UIScrollViewDelegate extension

Tags: ios, swift

Can I use **protocol extensions** for UIScrollViewDelegate to offer a default implementation of `scrollViewDidScroll` to all my views that conforms to this protocol?

Because I want to be able to in a single file propagate the same scrollViewDidScroll implementations through all my other views, without having to implement this method in each view, which are 6.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to implement the extension on the type implementing the protocol, i.e. UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController{
     func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        //do something
        print("scrolled\n")
    }
}
```

In Swift 2.0 only: It seems like you should be able to do something like below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
extension UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Any implementation of scrollViewDidScroll you write in a type that conforms to this protocol I believe should overwrite this implementation.

Comment: Swift 2.0 only by the way! Protocol extensions are a new feature in Swift 2.0

Comment: I've just tried it, but didn't work. What i'd really like to do is in a single file implement the behavior of all scroll views of all views in order to not having to re-implement it on each file of each view controller.

Comment: For example, I have 2 View Controllers which contains a webView and for each one i have a file. Both conform to UIScrollViewDelegate. But the implementation of scrollViewDidScroll are the same in both, so i would not like to replicate what i have done once.

Comment: yeah,.. not sure why extension on the protocol does not work, although an extension on UIViewController works.

Comment: It worked with computed properties, but when i try with event methods, it doesn't work...

Comment: That new solution you suggested worked for me as well!. Thanks :)